# How do I need to get My dropdownlist box value to the controller using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi I have this code in my view..

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("ProductTemplate",new SelectList(Model.ProductTemplate,"Value","Text"))%>
```

I know if this dropdownlist box is in between BeginForm submit I can able to access the value in Controller using `collection["ProductTemplate"];`

if it is not in my beginForm still I can able to access this selected value in controller?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use AJAX to send the value of the currently selected element to a controller action. This is pretty trivial with jQuery:

```
$.post('/home/foo', { productTemplate: $('#ProductTemplate').val() }, function(data) {
    alert(data.success);
});
```

And to access the selected value in your controller action simply use a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string productTemplate)
{
    // TODO: do something with the selected productTemplate
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Comment: @rockers, see my update, you could use an action parameter named `productTemplate`, which is the same name as the parameter sent in the AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks for your time Darin, My situation is something differnt..I have three grids in my view, each grid has beginform.. but on the top of the page I have thid dropdown list box..if I am going to keep this dorpdownlist box in first grid begin form in action result I can able to access the value, but I am not able to keep this dropdownlist box again in second beginfrom so to avoid that I thought of doing something like this is that right what I am thikning here?

thanks

Comment: @rockers, in this case you could register for the `submit` event using jQuery for the three forms in order to intercept the event when a form is about to be submitted to the server and then append the selected value of the dropdown to either a hidden field inside the form or to the action url as query string parameter. I would probably use a hidden field. This way you will be able to retrieve the selected value in the controller action that each form is posting to.

Answer (score 1):

If the control in not inside the form tag you will not get its value in controller. The workaround could be.

1) Create a hidden field inside form

2) OnChange event of your dropdown assign the selected value to the hidden field

**Edit**

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("ProductTemplate",new SelectList(Model.ProductTemplate,"Value","Text"),new {@onchange="setVal()"})%>
.
.
<form>
.
.
<input type="hidden" id="myval" name="myval"/>
.
.
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setVal()
{
$("#myval").val($("#ProductTemplate").val());
}
</script>
```

now in your controller you can get the value as `collection["myval"]`

Comment: Thanks ajay, please could provide any sample code for me thanks